# What typefaces would go well with Metalista?

Tags: typography

[Metalista](http://suitcasetype.com/index.php?lmut=en&part=fonts&font=24) is a modern blackletter font (afaik :)) designed by Suitcase Type Foundry as a tribute to "the persistency of the metal culture."

What other typefaces (used as subtitles) would mix best with Metalista (used for the title)?

In case that's too broad a question, here's an example narrowing: How well does [Steinem](http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Steinem.htm) go with Metalista?

To give you a bit of context, the above question(s) arose discussing a "steampunk" YA book cover for which Metalista is a good choice.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are no hard and fast rules for how to combine typefaces though there are a few approaches that people like to take - [this article by H&FJ is interesting](http://www.typography.com/email/2010_03/index_tw.htm).  To summarise, you could choose typefaces that give similar moods, typefaces from similar historical periods, typefaces with similar qualities, etc.  Keep in mind however that their article is intended to help sell you their fonts.

I think your typeface has such a dominating, in-your-face personality that you'll probably need to throw all those rules out the window.

What might make sense, however, is to choose something with a similar character and style, even if it has a different weight - by this I mean something angular rather than curvy - something more on the bold geometric side rather than humanistic.  However, Steinem doesn't fit either of those - it's got lots of extra elegant curves.

Sorry, these aren't free fonts, but to give you an idea: [Borda](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/northernblock/borda/), [Offense](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/reserves/offense/) or even something like this [TX NineVolt](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typebox/tx-ninevolt-bolt/) which is kinda angular despite being script-y.

Answer (score 1):

Font pairing is a pretty common designer problem. I can't answer your question and will stay away from giving you any feedback because that's not my area of expertise. But I will point out a website ([Font Fuse](http://fontfuse.webink.com/)) that provides an online community for suggesting and voting on font pairings. Font Fuse is primarily meant for use with web fonts offered by Extensis WebINK but it *might* allow you to upload your own fonts and ask the community to vote (not sure).